# @fontface not finding font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use the Entyo font face but I'm unable to get it working.  I changed the whole of the site to the font and can notice a distinct pause whena  page is being loaded, searchign for but not finding the font perhaps?

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
src: url('fonts/entypo-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/entypo-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/entypo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/entypo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/entypo-webfont.svg#EntypoRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

the fonts folder is in the root directory.

Thanks

EDIT:

Folder structure:

```
Main
-> fonts
-> -> entypo.eot
-> -> entypo.svg
-> -> entypo.ttf
-> -> entypowoff
-> CSS
-> -> stylesheet with @fontface call
-> includes
-> Etc etc
```

Updated url to //fonts/entypo.eot and so on.  Fonts are being loaded and are visible in web dev inspector but still not displaying on screen.  Only tested in safari and chrome, same result for both

EDIT: CSS Details.

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
    src: url('//fonts/entypo-webfont.eot');
    src: url('//fonts/entypo-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('//fonts/entypo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('//fonts/entypo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('//fonts/entypo-webfont.svg#EntypoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
html { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; } /*global improvement on all fonts*/

body {
    font-family: "EntypoRegular", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue",  Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size-adjust:inherit;

}
```

I removed everything that wasn't necessary

Comment: External stylesheet or is the above css in the page itself? If in the page, where is the page in relation to the root?

Comment: Check out your browser's element inspector's "net" tab to see whether it's the font requests that take so long

Comment: @PeteScott External stylesheet but all other styles are being applied and are functional.

Comment: Ok. Remember that the path to the font files would be relative to this stylesheet. If this stylesheet is in the root of the site, your paths are fine. Otherwise they are not. If you can provide us with an overview of your directory structure, we can be a bit more specific (and more certain about whether this is the issue, too)

Comment: @PeteScott -.- Amateur.  Changed the path for fonts.  No longer receiving a 404 error and I can see the font in web inspector.  Still not actually displaying though.

Comment: I've edited post to show folder structure.  The fonts are being located now but still not displaying.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you can post your complete css?

Comment: I'll update with the main details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to summarize:
First issue was due to slightly off relative path, which is all sorted. Now your paths are correct and you've verified the fonts are being loaded but not actually used (out of curiousity, how did you verify that?).

Possiple cuplrits: erroneous css (the bit you posted looks fine), browser compatability (what browser/version are you using?), corrupted font files (try re-downloading).

If you fire up the console/dom inspector tool in whatever browser you are using and check to see what css is being applied, can you tell if the font-family is being overridden by some other rule?

Comment: My apologies, you already told me how you verified the fonts were loading and which browsers you are using.

Comment: There's a chance I might have dynamic links and there's a chance I may have been logged out whilst working on the links that are displayed when logged in...thank you for all your help, after all that though, it doesn't look how I wanted it after all :)

Comment: Murphy's law. Thanks for adding all the extra details. Good luck!

Comment: yup:) Although...Now I've cleaned up the code etc, it still doesn't look like the font is displaying properly.  An '*' is represented by an arrow for example.  I'm still seeing an '*', any idea?

Comment: Oh... ENTYPO. I read that like eight times and nothing clicked. Does their stylesheet already have all the character maps set up for you?

Comment: yeah, i just tried using &#59273; from their char map to test and nothing except a little square appears instead of a mouse

Comment: That is, using the phone as an example, and their character map (http://www.entypo.com/characters/) as a guide, do you already have a rule like this in your css: .phone.icon:before{content:"\0021"}

Comment: For the mouse, try something like this: .mouse.icon:before{content:"\0023"} (assuming the :before stuff is already set up too)

Comment: No to both, I was working from this example: http://designfromwithin.com/blog-webdesign-development/2012/04/16/tutorial-cta-button-without-images-using-css3-and-entypo/#the_tutorial

Thanks for the fiddle, I think I'll use that method instead.

Comment: So, I copied the whole of that fiddle with the exception of the @fontface declaration into my page.  The icons are still not displaying. -.-

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33444/discussion-between-pete-scott-and-steve-green)

Answer (score 0):

Are the elements of your site actually using the font?

```
body {
  font-family: 'EntypoRegular', your-other-fallback-fonts;
}
```

Comment: no,what you wrote is literally what I had to test.  It's choosing my fallback every time.

 font-family: "EntypoRegular", "Helvetica Neue Light",     "Helvetica Neue",  Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;